# Should I export my logo with the padding?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, logo, export

I have finished my logo and I have a question to if it is correct to add the background with padding or not. The content is of course not what you see below, but the shape of it is. My logo consist of a horizontal rectangle that has white edges on black background.

When I shall export this, should I apply some padding around it so the white border that makes up the rectangle is visible? Or should I export it without the black background and specify that you must have at least X number of pixels/inches padding that is black around it?

The logo will be used on cars, web and printed material. I wonder if I should add the black background in the logo itself with some padding so you can see the rectangle stroke.

The black and white version:
[image: Main black and white logo]

Color version:
[image: Main color logo]

Inverse version:
[image: Inverse logo]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

You can add any padding via CSS if this goes up to a website, or just add white space around it if you're going to prepare a printed item. The amount of minimum white space can be defined similar to the below (check out their full corporate guidelines [document](https://www.cloudaccess.net/about-us/brand-manual.html)).

Depending on the background colour of each item (web or print), use either the b&w or the inversed version. It is usual for a logo to be prepared in full colour (like the one below), plus a monochrome (b&w) version, and in some cases a reversed b&w version.

[image]

Comment: Updated the question, the last sentences of the question.

Comment: So you suggest that I just leave the logo without any additional padding. Is that correct? But should I create a design document then that states that minimum black padding from the stroke should be X pixels/inches?

Comment: Edited my answer.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for how to do. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

Most brand guidelines offer a suggested amount of white space around any logotype. This is done to prevent visual confusion when the logo is used.

[image]

While it's definitely possible to add padding later, building this padding directly into the file ensures it remains consistently proportional upon scaling and won't be overlooked.

Comment: Mmm not sure about this. I have worked with a ton of identities and received many logos. Never seen one exported with any white space included. Sure, sometimes there's white space on the canvas of the vector file, but never on the raster exports (which i presume is what the OP is asking about). Going through most branding manuals you will see they usually define this "safe area" as a rule to be followed and don't enforce the white space on the actual downloadable files.

Comment: Clearly you disagree @Lucian :) Just because I feel you *should* do this, it doesn't mean you must agree or that everyone actually *does* do this. However, it is a *very good* practice to get accustomed to. "2x" can *easily* be built into a file. But figuring out 2x every single time you use a logo is something *many* won't do. Resulting in brand misuse.

Comment: Sure i can see your argument does make sense, but i still think it is very unusual and i think i have seen plenty of logos in my time. But i'm sure you did too :) Including white space could actually be confusing for people who are just given such a logo with no context. How do you space out a logo which is already spaced out?

Comment: Okay. My experience differs.

Comment: @Metis Could you explain what the 2x is? I mean, is it based on something in the logo or how did they come up with this space?

Comment: @Andreas yes `x` is based upon a width for part of the logo. In the LinkedIn logo it's the width of the `i`. So, unless you intend to measure the `i` with every use, then multiply that by 2, then ensure the padding matches that value, the branding would be inconsistent. Or... you just build the padding into the logo file itself. visit www.brandsoftheworld.com - register and download a few logos, you'll find built in padding in all logos of more well-known corporations.

Answer (score 1):

If you **always always always** want a certain amount of padding/margin around your artwork, consider that white space part of the logotype's artwork when you export. If you want flexibility, export different versions of the file. Don't assume the correct padding will always be there with CSS because logos are often hosted or collaged outside of your control. The larger the company, the harder it is to police brand standard manuals. Exhibit A:

[image: 1]